# JQuery GET request to TCP socket server

Tags: jquery, c, sockets, tcp, webserver

I ve written a really simple TCP server in C that uses sockets.  I'd like to establish a back and forth from the server to a web interface using JQuery get and post operations.

At this stage, the only functionality i have implemented is the GET operation, and the server listens and returns a string upon connection.  This works, however, not with JQuery (or JS).  The odd thing is when i directly input the servers IP and port into the browsers address bar, the string is displayed?

I am using box standard JQuery on a local host.

Any suggestions?

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("127.0.0.1:800",function(data){
            alert("Data: " + data );
    });
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>GET</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Server

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int sockd, sockd2;
  int addrlen;
  struct sockaddr_in my_name, peer_name;
  int status;

  /* create a socket */
  sockd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockd == -1)
  {
    perror("Socket creation error");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (argc < 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s port_number\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* server address  */
  my_name.sin_family = AF_INET;
  my_name.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  my_name.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

  status = bind(sockd, (struct sockaddr*)&my_name, sizeof(my_name));
  if (status == -1)
  {
    perror("Binding error");
    exit(1);
  }

  status = listen(sockd, 5);
  if (status == -1)
  {
    perror("Listening error");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(;;)
  {
    /* wait for a connection */
    addrlen = sizeof(peer_name);
    sockd2 = accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr*)&peer_name, &addrlen);
    if (sockd2 == -1)
    {
      perror("Wrong connection");
      exit(1);
    }
    write(sockd2, "Hello!\n", 7);
    close(sockd2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there errors in the Javascript console? What does it say in the Network tab of developer tools?

Comment: If you want specific help, you have to post the code. How can we tell what you did wrong if we don't see it?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery expects your server to be an HTTP server, but you are not speaking HTTP. Your browser *shouldn't* be able to display your message either.

In HTTP the client sends a request, then the server sends a response. The connection can then be closed immediately (simplest) or reused for future requests (because it's faster than making a new connection).

A bare-minimum HTTP request (what the client sends) looks like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

and the response (what the server sends) looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello!
```

The server would close the connection after sending the response. It must close the connection "gracefully" with `shutdown` - *not* just with `close` as this might prevent the client from seeing the entire response.

Note that there is a `\r\n` at the end of each line, not just `\n`.

You should at least read [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) which is the HTTP/1.1 specification, if you want to write a correct web server. (Of course, if you're after a quick hack, you could ignore whatever the client sends, and always send a fixed response like the one above.)